# not able to increase ubuntu VM disk size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, hard-disk, vmware

I have increased disk size of the VM from vmware player from 30G to 50G. I am not able to figure how to extend the partition inside the Ubuntu server (VM).

Is it possible to increase /dev/sda1 to 50G?

guest os: ubuntu 64bit 16.04
vmware workstation 12 player

```
#fdisk -l
...
...

Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0001183e

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 58722303 58720256  28G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       58724350 62912511  4188162   2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       58724352 62912511  4188160   2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
root@ubs:~# 
root@ubs:~# 
root@ubs:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           394M  5.8M  388M   2% /run
/dev/sda1        28G   13G   14G  48% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/1000
root@ubs:~#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that sda2 and sda5 are "in the way".  Fortunately sda5 is just swap and so doesn't contain any persistent data.

The steps would be:

1. Disable all swapping.  This will make sda5 free to be deleted.
2. Delete sda5
3. Delete sda2
4. Resize sda1
5. Create sda2
6. Create sda5
7. mkswap sda5
8. swapon
9. resizefs /

This might be easier from the console in single user mode, but *may* be doable without any reboot needed.

Answer (score 1):

Given your configuration, it is possible but extremely time-consuming to extend `/dev/sda1`. You must first move `sda2` and `sda5` to the end of the disk, which will likely require backing up the data, deleting the partitions, extending `/dev/sda1`, recreating the 2 and 5 partitions, and restoring the data on those partitions. You can then expand the filesystem on `/dev/sda1` to use the entirety of the new space.